# Faster way to delete Contact in Salesforce (Simple_Salesforce)

Tags: python, salesforce, sql-delete, simple-salesforce

I'm working in a sandbox and I need to often delete hundreds of rows. I'm currently using `simple_salesfroce`to achive it. But my script take long time when I need to delete large amount of row.

My script:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


username="#####"
password="#####"
security_token="######"
domain="test"

sf = Salesforce(username=username,password=password, security_token=security_token,domain=domain)

#### QUERY #### 
results=sf.query_all("""
    Select id,Name FROM Contact where CreatedById='########' and RecordTypeId = '#######'
    """)

#print(results)

records = [dict(id=rec['Id'], 
                Name=rec['Name']) 
                for rec in results['records']]
df=pd.DataFrame(records)

for i in tqdm(df.id):
    sf.Contact.delete(i)
print('Contacts deleted')
```

Is there a faster way to do it ? For instance it takes nearly an hour to delete 5000 rows. The creation of the dataframe is a matter of secondes, only the deleting process takes time.

Answer (score 1):

you're deleting 1 contact at a time, in a loop. You waste more time on network roundtrips than the actual delete takes. Plus this will consume lots of API calls and in extreme cases - exhaust your limit of daily API calls, especially in production.

See if you can pass a list to delete operation?

Or use bulk api (but it's asynchronous operation), it's described towards the end of readme: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#using-bulk